# Removing and inserting td's within a table using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

This HTML markup is fixed and can not be modified directly:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td id="LeftPanel">A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I'm trying to use jQuery to change the markup to this:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td id="LeftPanel">A</td>
            <td>C</td>
            <td id="RightPanel">D</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

1. The TD directly after #LeftPanel needs to be removed (B).
2. A new TD with the id #RightPanel needs to be added to the end of the table (D).

Note that the full source has many tables on the same level so the only reference point to work with is td#LeftPanel. The A B C D is just there for reference and can't be used as part of the script (the full source has a lot of HTML in each TD, including nested tables).

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: checking this out already almost have solution for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/

```
$('#LeftPanel')
        .next()
        .remove()
        .end()
        .parent()
        .append('<td id="rightPanel">D</td>');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/msKvR/

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you for your reply and also the additional info. jQuery is new to me but I'm finding it very exciting thus far.  StackOverflow rocks!

Comment: if you have more than one table with id of "LeftPanel" in the td, this solution can't possibly work (though it does with classes) - you must use classes instead in your HTML markup, and this code would change to .LeftPanel and td CLASS="RightPanel".

Comment: @sajawikio No worries, but now your answer is similar to mine. Isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('td#LeftPanel ~ td ').remove(); // remove b
$('td#LeftPanel ~ td ').append('<td id="RightPanel">D</td>'); // add d
```

Comment: This removed many other elements within the source and also removed all TD's except for LeftPanel. To be fair, it might be because of the full source code rather than your script. Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use duplicate ID's if you have more than one table

Do this instead:

JS:

```
$('.LeftPanel')
        .next()
        .remove()
        .end()
        .parent()
        .append('<td class="RightPanel">D</td>');
```

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="LeftPanel">A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="LeftPanel">A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="LeftPanel">A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: (B) was removed as intended but (D) was added to the first table in the markup (rather than the table with td#LeftPanel). I'm guessing this script would work fine if you only have one table on the page. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: if you have more than one table you can't have LeftPanel as id. Instead, use classes, and you can do what it says in my updated answer

Comment: The other tables don't have #LeftPanel (it is unique to that table). I think it's because your original code was just looking for a tr.     $("#LeftPanel").next().remove();
    $("table").find("tr").eq(0).append("<td id='RightPanel'>D</td>");